# SQL query issues: [1] Count(*) and [2] using NOT vs <>

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been staring at this code so long it is starting to bleed together. So let's get a couple things out of the way:

1. I am a low-moderate level SQL user and am still learning the best ways to accomplish queries and such
2. I have been building a PHP based quote-generator tool that ties in with an SQL database

Now, here is what I am trying to accomplish:
I would like to have pagination with the results of quotes that have been created with a status that is NOT "Dead", "Duplicate", or "Signed" and the ID does NOT equal 999 (because I wanted the quotes to jump to 1000 and I did not build the database correctly at first)

Here is what I have accomplished:
I was able to create the basic structure and it works just fine on page 1... then it all goes sideways. I was thinking that it was something to do with my count(*) query, but that seems fine - well functional, at least:

```
$countQry = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
             from needsassessment 
             WHERE ID <> 999 
               AND status <> 'Dead' 
               AND status <> 'Duplicate' 
               AND status <> 'Signed'";

$countResult = $mysqli->query($countQry);
while($rowQ = mysqli_fetch_array($countResult)) {
    $totalRows = $rowQ[0];
    $each = ceil($totalRows/$limit);
    $where = "WHERE ID > 0";
    if ($totalRows == 0) {
        echo "You have not created any quotes.";
    }
}

$limit = 15;
if (isset($_GET['q']) && $_GET['q'] !== "") {
    $offset = $_GET['q'];
} else {
    $offset = 0;
}     

$query = "SELECT * FROM needsassessment $where
          where $and 
            AND ID <> 999 
            AND NOT status = 'Dead' 
            AND NOT status = 'Duplicate' 
            AND NOT status = 'Signed' 
          ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $offset, $limit";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($row_cnt == 0) {
    echo "You have not created any quotes."; die;
}
if (!isset($each)) {
    $each = $row_cnt/$limit;
}

if ($each > 1) {
    echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
    for($i=1,$y=0;$i<=$each,$y<=($each-1);$i++,$y++) {  
        echo "<li><a";
        if ($offset == ($y*15)) {echo ' class="active"';}
            echo " href='?q=".($y*15)."'>$i</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

Okay, so here are my questions:

1. I saw someone say that using PHP's mysqli_num_rows() is wrong and
   that I should use SQL's COUNT(*). Why? Does it have a different result or take longer?
2. What is going on with page's
   2 and 3? When I do a row count it says it sees 15 rows but only some
   are showing. I have some records (i.e. those with a status of
   "Signed" or "Dead") that are excluded from this list and I was
   thinking that may have been the issue, but it doesn't seem to matter
   on the first page.
3. What is the difference - if there is one -
   between "NOT" and "<>" for checking records?
4. If you have any suggestions or if I have done anything blatantly wrong or inefficiently please let me know so I can correct it :)

Thanks to all that make Stack Overflow AWESOME!

EDIT:
There certainly was some code missing:

```
if (!isset($sst)) {
    $where = "";
    $sst = "";
$countQry = "SELECT COUNT(*) from needsassessment WHERE ID <> 999 AND status <> 'Dead' AND status <> 'Duplicate' AND status <> 'Signed'";
$countResult = $mysqli->query($countQry);
while($rowQ = mysqli_fetch_array($countResult)) {
$totalRows = $rowQ[0];
$each = ceil($totalRows/$limit);
$where = "WHERE ID > 0";
if ($totalRows == 0) {echo "You have not created any quotes.";}
}
}
else {
    if ($option !== "*") {
    $where = "WHERE ".$option." LIKE '%".$sst."%'";
    }
    if ($option == "*") {
    $where = "WHERE status LIKE '%".$sst."%' OR title LIKE '%".$sst."%' OR propType LIKE '%".$sst."%' OR pSType LIKE '%".$sst."%' OR createDate LIKE '%".$sst."%'";
    }
    $offset = 0;
}
    if ($_SESSION['admin'] >= 1) {
    $and = "";
    }
    else {
    $and = "AND creatorID = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
    }
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You are using `$limit` in this line `$each = ceil($totalRows/$limit);` before you set a value for `$limit = 15;`

Comment: I dont see anywhere where you set `$and` to be used in the query

Comment: This query is all messed up `$query = "SELECT * FROM needsassessment $where where $and` take a slow careful look at it

Comment: I've added the missing code to the post

Comment: A bit puzzled that you `COUNT()` but that you do not `GROUP BY` anything ...

Comment: @MikeRobinson Would you recommend grouping by status or company name? I order my results from newest to oldest and that is how I want them to display but do you think would that help to display all the records correctly without gaps?

Comment: Just *try* it.  **:-)**  You'll see instantly how it works, and what is right for your present needs.  (Notice that the `GROUP BY` fields, if any, must also appear in the `SELECT` clause, for fairly obvious reasons.)

Comment: @MikeRobinson Thank you! I'll try it out :) Learning opportunities! :)

Comment: Yeah.  It's seriously fun *(well, in a **very** "geeky" sort of way)* to set up your own dummy-database, fill it with some garbage data, and then just start "throwing queries at it" using an appropriate interactive tool. (In other words, "not 'writing [PHP] programs.") In the comfort of your own home (or, dorm-room), you can very quickly *figure out* just how a lot of these things work. It's a self-education well worth doing. Also, visit any number of "SQL tutorials" sites and *actually go through* their entire series (including "homework"). The "little light-bulbs" will turn on quickly.